# How to allow articles to occupy full browser height

Tags: html, css

I want to display first at top left, second at top right, third at bottom left and fourth at bottom left.

Currently it is displayed as: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAWS9.png)

But it is not taking full height. I want to display top two articles to be 50% of height and the rest 50% to bottom articles.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

article:first-child {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: static;
  background-color: red;
}

article:nth-child(2){
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: static;
  background-color: yellow;
}

article:nth-child(3){
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: static;
  background-color: green;
}

article:nth-child(4){
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: static;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<article>First</article>
<article>Second</article>
<article>third</article>
<article>fourth</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox*** and *viewport units*, where `50vw` & `50vh` mean *50%* of the *viewport* `width` and `height`:

```css
body {
  display: flex; /* displays childen inline by default */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* enables wrapping */
  width: 100vw; /* added */
  height: 100vh; /* modified */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

article:first-child {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  /*float: left;*/
  /*position: static;*/
  background-color: red;
}

article:nth-child(2) {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  /*float: left;*/
  /*position: static;*/
  background-color: yellow;
}

article:nth-child(3) {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  /*float: left;*/
  /*position: static;*/
  background-color: green;
}

article:nth-child(4) {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  /*float: left;*/
  /*position: static;*/
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<article>First</article>
<article>Second</article>
<article>third</article>
<article>fourth</article>
```

*Note:* No need for `float`s and `position: static` which is by default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `min-height: 50%;` or better still `height: 50vh;`